# Observer in magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, php-7

I want to get zipcode in **sales->order->addressEdit** using the event .

it's working fine.

**Event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_sales_order_address_update">
        <observer name="verify_cod" instance="Xxx\Sales\Pincode" />
    </event>
</config>
```

But I want to the observer before addressSave controller execution ...
I also trying..

```
controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_addressSave
```

My page not redirect to address page...

please tell me how to do it.

Comment: try controller action predispatch event

Comment: But it does not redirect page...